# Referencing table showing customized text

Tags: tables, hyperref

I have questions about how to show customized text when referencing the table.

For example, the table below is the 11th table in my document. It's customized label is Table:S3.

When referencing to the table, I hope it could show in its customized tag, like below:

```
The general disease genes are listed in Table:S3
```

However, when i reference it with

```
The general disease genes are listed in ~\ref{Table:S3}.
```

It displays

```
The general disease genes are listed in 11.
```

11 means it is the 11th table in my document.

I am wondering if there is a way to refer to the table but show the text I defined.

Here is how the table looks like

```
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \captionsetup{labelformat=empty}
    \caption{Supplementary table 3: Disease seed genes}
    \label{Table:S3}
    A & B \\
    \end{tabular}
 \end{table}
```

Comment: Huh? You show the label? Btw **don't use option `H`!!!**

Comment: @JouleV I hope to show the label when referring to that table in the main text. It would be even better if I can define what is shown when I refer to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `\hyperref`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}
\newcommand\myref[1]{\hyperref[#1]{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[t]
    \centering
    \captionsetup{labelformat=empty}
    \caption{Supplementary table 3: Disease seed genes}
    \label{Table:S3}
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
    A & B \\
    \end{tabular}
 \end{table}

Now we refer to~\myref{Table:S3}. Now we refer to~\hyperref[Table:S3]{Blah blah}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different possibility using `newfloat` and `cleveref`. I have defined a new float type `supptable` with the caption prefix `Supplementary Table`. What is displayed in the reference to the table can be altered using the `\crefname` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[name={Supplementary Table}]{supptable}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefname{supptable}{Supplementary Table}{Supplementary Tables}

\begin{document}
\begin{supptable}
    \centering
    \caption{Disease seed genes}
    \label{Table:S3}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
    A & B \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{supptable}

See \cref{Table:S3}
\end{document}
```